Windows Task Scheduler not working with 'Run whether user is logged on or not'
Context
At my workplace, there is a webserver which uses task scheduler. In the morning, three scripts run which pull data from SAPGUI & SQL and uploads it into an Excel sheet. Once the task finishes, it closes it down and waits till the next run. It is set to 'run whether user is logged on or not'.
Now for some reason, about 3 months ago, it just doesn't work anymore. The scripts have never been changed, and the network hasn't changed either. When running with 'run only when user is logged on' it works fine, no issues at all.
When you select 'run whether user is logged on or not' (like it needs to be) it runs but nothing happens. This is now happening on the other web server too. I have tried recreating the tasks, changing the permissions (all at maximum), I've checked history which just says task completed. When I run manually, it works as normal. So for the last few months we've had to log on early AM to kick these off when they should be running themselves.
The task activates PowerShell and runs a .ps1 script from C: location. Again it works fine when it's run manually or when the user is always logged in. It just fails/doesn't do anything when the other option is selected.
To clarify:

rebooted
set highest permissions
running with admin account, it works because we have signed in with it
SAP user has admin permissions
SQL user has admin permissions
scripts unchanged
closed excel sessions in computer management
logs/events do not have any info

Really running out of options. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

How are you using Excel within the script? If you are running the exe or using Excel.Application automation then this is a possible cause as running Excel in that fashion (from a non-interactive user session) has never been supported & is brittle. Remove the Excel step and instead try writing the data to a flat file to confirm this.  If you are doing something else then try adding as much logging as possible to identify the point of failure.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

powershell -command script.ps1 > script.log 2>&1
